# Duplicate image download issue in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, contentful

Two components are used to process the image operation. First component is **ShowFormsList**  inside it **onDownloadFile** is used and another component **ShowImgList** which is used to pass **onDownloadFile** method and **ImgList** as props .

**ShowFormsList.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {
  Subheading,
  Accordion,
  AccordionItem,
} from "@contentful/forma-36-react-components";
import Jarvis from "../../utils/Jarvis";
import LoadingContext from "../../context/LoadingContext";
import ShowImgList from "./ShowImgList";

const ShowFormsList = ({ sdk }) => {
  const [view, setView] = React.useState(null);
  const jarvisSdk = new Jarvis(sdk);
  const { showLoading, hideLoading } = useContext(LoadingContext);
  const fieldType = (sdk && sdk.field.id) || "";
  // const [update, setUpdate] = React.useState(false);

  const autoScroll = () => {
    sdk.window.startAutoResizer();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    sdk.window.startAutoResizer();
  });

  const getFormData = async () => {
    showLoading();

    const formData = await jarvisSdk.getFormData(sdk.ids.entry);
    const formArr =
      formData &&
      formData.length > 0 &&
      formData.map((form) => {
        const formObj = {
          formName: form.formName,
          formId: form.id,
          formDescription: form.description,
        };

        // const imgArr = [];
        const imgArr =
          form.formImages &&
          form.formImages.length > 0 &&
          form.formImages.map((img) => {
            console.log(img);
            const imgObj = {
              imageName: img.imageName,
              type: img.type,
              extension: img.imageName.split(".")[1],
              id: img.id,
            };
            // imgArr.push(imgObj);
            return imgObj;
          });
        formObj.images = imgArr;
        return formObj;
        // formArr.push(formObj);
      });
    if (formArr && formArr.length > 0) {
      setView(formArr);
    }
    hideLoading();
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    await getFormData();
  }, []);

  const onDownloadFile = async (id) => {
    showLoading();
    const downloadedFile = await jarvisSdk.downloadFormFile(id, fieldType);

    const contentDispositionHeader = downloadedFile.responseObj.request
      .getResponseHeader("Content-disposition")
      .split("filename=");
    const fileName =
      contentDispositionHeader[contentDispositionHeader.length - 1];
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([downloadedFile.blob]));
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("download", `${fileName}`);
    link.setAttribute("id", Math.random() + fileName);
    link.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    link.remove();
    hideLoading();
  };
  return (
    <>
      {view && view.length > 0 && (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="Card">
            <div className="container">
              <Accordion>
                {view.map((item) => (
                  <AccordionItem
                    key={item.formId}
                    title={
                      <a
                        className="text-decoration"
                        href={`https://app.contentful.com/spaces/${sdk.ids.space}/environments/${sdk.ids.environment}/entries/${item.formId}`}
                        target="_black"
                      >
                        {item.formName}
                      </a>
                    }
                    onExpand={() => autoScroll()}
                    onCollapse={() => autoScroll()}
                  >
                    <ShowImgList
                      key={item.formId}
                      images={item.images}
                      onDownloadFile={onDownloadFile}
                      sdk={sdk}
                    />
                  </AccordionItem>
                ))}
              </Accordion>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}

      {!view && (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="Card">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="dropZoneContainer">
                <div className="Dropzone">
                  <Subheading className="d-color">No data found.</Subheading>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const propTypes = {
  sdk: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object),
};

ShowFormsList.defaultProps = {
  sdk: undefined,
};

ShowFormsList.propTypes = propTypes;

export default ShowFormsList;
```

The second component is used to call the **onDownloadFile** method and perform the UI part operation.

**ShowImgList.jsx**

```
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TabPanel,
  Icon,
} from "@contentful/forma-36-react-components";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const ShowImgList = (props) => {
  const { images, onDownloadFile, sdk } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    sdk.window.startAutoResizer();
  });
  const defaultTab = "first";
  return (
    <div className="fileVersionContainer">
      <TabPanel id={defaultTab} className="versionContainer">
        <div>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Image</TableCell>
                <TableCell>File Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Type</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Download</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {images &&
                images.length > 0 &&
                images.map((aImg) => (
                  <TableRow key={aImg.id}>
                    <TableCell key={`${aImg.id}cell`}>
                      <Icon key={`${aImg.id}asset`} icon="Asset" />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell key={`-name-${aImg.id}`}>
                      {aImg.imageName}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell key={`-type-${aImg.id}`}>
                      {aImg.extension}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell key={`-download-${aImg.id}`}>
                      <Icon
                        icon="Download"
                        className="cursor-pointer"
                        onClick={() => onDownloadFile(aImg.id)}
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
};

const propTypes = {
  sdk: PropTypes.instanceOf(Object),
  images: PropTypes.instanceOf(Array),
  onDownloadFile: PropTypes.func,
};

ShowImgList.defaultProps = {
  sdk: undefined,
  images: undefined,
  onDownloadFile: undefined,
};

ShowImgList.propTypes = propTypes;

export default ShowImgList;
```

Comment: You need to share the code that called the method "onDownloadFile()"

Comment: please suggest me what is the root cause of this issue and their solution through code.

Comment: You will need to look at the codes that call this function and not this function itself. That was why I asked you to share the calling code

Comment: This time i put the whole code before this i have not put all the code because some extra code is also inside it.

Comment: This time everything is perfect i have checked through debugger please watch the code of ShowFormsList.jsx code and give some solution.

Comment: Ok so I believe you have modified the original question considerably (in a good way by being more descriptive). Let me just rehash the issue that you are facing. When you click to download a file, the message "File successfully downloaded. Refresh the page to see updated file." appears twice and the file is similarly downloaded twice correct?

Comment: When my UI is open then the list of images is open means there are four image list and for every image there is a seprate download button appers but when we download every image seprately we get only same image on every download button from the imagelist but the image name is different on every download but when i open the image after download i get all four images are same.

Comment: what does this component do --> `jarvisSdk.downloadFormFile`

Comment: ` async downloadFormFile(id) {
    try {
      const file = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${this.jarvisApiEndpoint}/forms/image/${id}/download`,
        responseType: 'blob',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
        },
      });
      return { blob: file.data, responseObj: file };
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }`

Comment: jarvis is the name of service where downloadFormFile is written.

Comment: const jarvisSdk = new Jarvis(sdk);

Comment: OK this is a little hard. Just looking at some inconsistencies in your code that might result in this weird behaviour. One of them is the multiple `key` attributes in the table displaying the list of files. Just use a single key defined on the  `TableRow` and remove the rest of them and see if that works